# How to use test cards for squareup merchant

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm currently integrating Squareup APIs for a project. We have a developer account and a merchant account. When I try to test the integration and test payment using Squareup payment form I am getting this error.

```
{"errors":[{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"INVALID_CARD","detail":"Invalid card number."}
```

When I try to use merchant terminal to charge, i'm getting card invalid error page.

Test cards. https://docs.connect.squareup.com/testing/test-values

How can I test credit card processing with test cards?

Comment: Are you testing the test cards in sandbox? Test cards will not work in production.

Comment: @Kaled We are in final stages of integration. I want to test full integration creating orders with items, modifiers, taxes, discounts and process the charge. How can we test full flow? (charge and see transactions). Current sandbox doesn't support all the functions. I'm currently stuck at card processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to view sandbox transactions is to call the [ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions) endpoint with your sandbox credentials to get a sandbox transaction report. Only live transactions will be visible on your Square Dashboard.

To test the full extent of our APIs you'll need to test in production. While there’s not currently a way to delete test transactions, you can definitely process a refund instead. It won’t remove the transactions from your history, but refunding the transaction will balance your books. If you’re not familiar with processing refunds, visit our [Support Center](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5060) for step-by-step instructions.

We're constantly working on adding more features to sandbox. I'll be sure to share your thoughts with the appropriate teams.